# How can I lock specific windows (NOT the entire application) to specific Spaces in Lion?

Tags: spaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can Spaces be configured by project, rather than by application?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42812/can-spaces-be-configured-by-project-rather-than-by-application)

I have a dual-display setup (27" iMac and a 30" Dell monitor) and I like to be able to have diferent types of work going on, in different Spaces on the machine.

This means I would like to have web browsers for work related stuff in one Space, browsers for personal stuff in another, and browsers for maybe some other project, in yet another Space.

I can easily assign an entire APPLICATION to a specific Space, and make new windows open in that space.  This is not what I want.  I want different windows of the SAME application, to "pin" to specific Spaces.  I can't find any way to do that.

I'm open to paid apps that provide this functionality, but major bonus points if you can come up with a free solution that's either baked-into the OS already, or maybe just uses some AppleScript or Terminal wizardry to accomplish the result.

I'm aware of this thread but it didn't have a real solution either:

[Can Spaces be configured by project, rather than by application?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42812/can-spaces-be-configured-by-project-rather-than-by-application)

Comment: Unfortunately the situation hasn't changed, assigning windows to Spaces is not possible. It might be quite difficult to provide anyway, e.g. how would you identify a window to configure it to a specific Space in the first place?

Comment: Yes it is a duplicate, attempting to find out if there has been anything new on the topic since the original was posted 3 months ago.

Comment: Just adding a *comment* to the original question will raise it to the top of the list again, no need to start another.

Comment: It doesn't appear possible for me to add comments to that topic, only answers and I don't have any.  That's why I started a new one.